Intellij IDEA Unresolved Symbol Warning in JPA Query
I have the following JPA query in a JpaRepository class within a Spring Boot application:
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT post.postId.date FROM Post post ORDER BY post.postId.date")
fun getPostDateList(): List<LocalDate>

It is warning me that it can't resolve "date" in both places. They query works just fine though, how can I tell Intellij to stop warning me about it?
The Post class:
class AEPost(
    @EmbeddedId
    val postId: PostId,
    @Column
    val positions: Int?
}

class PostId() : Serializable {
    @Column(columnDefinition = "date", nullable = false)
    var date: LocalDate = LocalDate.now()
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var name: String = ""
}


What's the exact type/fully qualified name of LocalDate? Is it a java.time.LocalDate, does it come from kotlinx.datetime or is it something else?

It's java.time.LocalDate

I could imagine this being due to the column being named date which is an SQL keyword. Can you try a different column name?
